# How to apply a function to more than one list of lists in r?

Tags: r, lapply

I have a data which contains list of lists. And I want to find max. values of each double type data as shown in the picture;

[image: output]

Here is structure of my data;

```
list(`Cluster 1` = list(Day_1 = list(structure(c(`1` = 0, `2` = 0, 
    `3` = 0, `4` = 0, `5` = 0, `6` = 0, `7` = 0, `8` = 0, `9` = 0.041, 
    `10` = 0.673, `11` = 0, `12` = 0.766), .Dim = 12L, .Dimnames = list(
        c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", 
        "12"))), structure(c(`1` = 0, `2` = 0, `3` = 0, `4` = 0, 
    `5` = 0, `6` = 0.041, `7` = 0.673, `8` = 0.766), .Dim = 8L, .Dimnames = list(
        c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8")))), Day_2 = list(
        structure(c(`1` = 1.07, `2` = 0, `3` = 1.27, `4` = 0.19, 
        `5` = 0, `6` = 0, `7` = 0, `8` = 0, `9` = 0, `10` = 0, `11` = 0, 
        `12` = 0), .Dim = 12L, .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", 
        "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"))), structure(c(`1` = 1.07, 
        `2` = 1.27, `3` = 0.19, `4` = 0, `5` = 0, `6` = 0, `7` = 0, 
        `8` = 0), .Dim = 8L, .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
        "5", "6", "7", "8"))))), `Cluster 2` = list(Day_3 = list(
        structure(c(`1` = 0, `2` = 0, `3` = 0, `4` = 0, `5` = 0, 
        `6` = 0, `7` = 0, `8` = 0, `9` = 0.19, `10` = 0, `11` = 0, 
        `12` = 0), .Dim = 12L, .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", 
        "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"))), structure(c(`1` = 0, 
        `2` = 0, `3` = 0, `4` = 0, `5` = 0, `6` = 0.19, `7` = 0, 
        `8` = 0), .Dim = 8L, .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
        "5", "6", "7", "8")))), Day_4 = list(structure(c(`1` = 0.521, 
    `2` = 0.229, `3` = 0, `4` = 0, `5` = 0, `6` = 0, `7` = 0, `8` = 0, 
    `9` = 0, `10` = 0, `11` = 0, `12` = 0), .Dim = 12L, .Dimnames = list(
        c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", 
        "12"))), structure(c(`1` = 0.75, `2` = 0, `3` = 0, `4` = 0, 
    `5` = 0, `6` = 0, `7` = 0, `8` = 0), .Dim = 8L, .Dimnames = list(
        c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))))))
```

I tried this code;

```
nested_lapply <- function(data, fun) {
    lapply(data, function(sublist) { lapply(sublist, fun) })
}
```

But I am getting this error

> ```
> res<-nested_lapply(out, max)
> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument
> Called from: lapply(sublist, fun)
> ```

**Addition to question:**

I need to find max. values for all [[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gtnK.png)]] and also [[2]].

max1<-max(out$`Cluster 1`$Day_1[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gtnK.png)], out$`Cluster 1`$Day_2[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gtnK.png)], out$`Cluster 2`$Day_3[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gtnK.png)], out$`Cluster 2`$Day_4[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gtnK.png)])

max2<-max(out$`Cluster 1`$Day_1[[2]], out$`Cluster 1`$Day_2[[2]], out$`Cluster 2`$Day_3[[2]], out$`Cluster 2`$Day_4[[2]])

Comment: ddo you need `rapply(out, max)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can just use `rapply` from `base R` which will recursively loop over the three nested `list` an get the `max` from the inner`vector`

```
rapply(out, max)
```

---

If we want across `max`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
reshape2::melt(out) %>% 
   group_by(L3) %>%
   summarise(value = max(value))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#    L3 value
#  <int> <dbl>
#1     1  1.27
#2     2  1.27
```

---

Or it could be

```
flatten(out) %>% 
      transpose %>% 
      map(reduce, pmax)
#[[1]]
#    1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12 
#1.070 0.229 1.270 0.190 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.190 0.673 0.000 0.766 

#[[2]]
#    1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8 
#1.070 1.270 0.190 0.000 0.000 0.190 0.673 0.766
```

Or a single value

```
flatten(out) %>% 
    transpose %>%
    map_dbl(reduce, max)
#[1] 1.27 1.27
```

Comment: This worked. But I need something else. I want to find max(Cluster 1.Day_11, Cluster 1.Day_21, Cluster 2.Day_31..). Briefly, single max. value between first elements of days (Day_1, Day_2) and then again second elements of days

Comment: @HüsamettinTayşi may be I am wrong. I read your description as ` find max. values of each double type data as shown in the picture;`. Can you show your expected output

Comment: Actually you were right. I am sorry for my bad explanation. I've edited the question.

Comment: @HüsamettinTayşi can you check my upddated post

Comment: After new code I am getting 20 values. But I want to get 2 values in the end. One value is single max. value of first [[1]] elements of each day and the second max. value is second [[2]] elements of each day. So both values should be 1.27.

Comment: @HüsamettinTayşi i update d the post.  Now, both are 1.27

Answer (score 1):

you can use this solution

```
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
  enframe() %>% 
  unnest_longer(value) %>% 
  unnest_longer(value) %>% 
  transmute(name, value_id, out = map_dbl(value, max))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```
lapply(1:length(data), function(X) lapply(data[[X]], FUN))
```